# how to clean persian string in php

Tags: php, string

I have an string like this:

```
    <div class="myclass">
ما قصد داریم تنها کاراکترهای فارسی را خارج کنیم. اما مشکلاتی پیش رو داریم, از جمله کاراکترهای خاص. آیا راهی هست؟ لطفا راهنمایی کنید.
</div>
```

now I want my output be like this one:

```
ما قصد داریم تنها کاراکترهای فارسی را خارج کنیم اما مشکلاتی پیش رو داریم از جمله کاراکترهای خاص آیا راهی هست لطفا راهنمایی کنید
```

i can't use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` because some time there is some character like `�`  in my output

Comment: [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the Multibyte String Functions.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Your Persian string uses multibyte character encoding, and str_replace() cannot handle that correctly (unless it is UTF-8 see comment below).

There are more issues:

1 Make sure you store the PHP file in the correct character encoding on the server (tip by Mark).

2 Also make sure you send the correct header in your HTML output, for instance:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

when using UTF8. And also do it in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Everything must be correct, or it will not work. Dealing with character encoding can be quite difficult. Have you seen the `mb_detect_encoding()` function? Use this on your original string to learn its encoding.

Comment: If it's UTF-8, then `str_replace()` and friends will work just fine.  You only need the `mb_` functions for encodings that allow the same byte values in different portions of a character's representation.

Comment: It is not wrking. problem is continue

Comment: can I use `mb_` for `str_replace()` ?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` this is not working too

Comment: @Mark: That's probably true, but which encoding is user3932710 using? We don't know. It's probably that he doesn't send the correct character encoding to the client.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - agreed.  I was just pointing out that you used UTF-8 in your example, but if that were correct, OP wouldn't be having this problem. :)

Comment: We need more information, user3932710.  What encoding is your PHP file being saved as?  What's the source of the Persian string?